# KMeans clustering for OpenAI embeddings using C#

Tags: c#, .net, cluster-analysis, openai-api

We calculated the embeddings using the OpenAI embeddings API on a set of documents and have the values stored in a CSV file for further processing.

One of the things we want to do is detect groups of similar documents like it is done in the [Clustering recipe](https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/clustering) on the OpenAI cookbook. Python has KMeans algoriths available in the `scikit-learn` package

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

n_clusters = 4

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, init="k-means++", random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(matrix)
labels = kmeans.labels_
df["Cluster"] = labels

df.groupby("Cluster").Score.mean().sort_values()
```

However we want to achieve this using C#, but we cannot find a proper nuget package providing a similar simple API.

Can anybody provide pointers or suggestions on how to do this?